# Open File handle limit on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, file-io

How can I find out the maximum number of file handles that can be open at once on a windows mobile device?

I am running a native C++ application on a windows mobile proffesional emulator and there seems to be a limit of 39 open file handles (strange number I know), where any other files I open after that returning the error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).

I have been unable to find the answers to the following questions:
1) What is the limit of open file handles, how to find this limit for different devices/platforms?

2) Why is error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) begin returned rather than error code 4 (ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES).

3) Why 39? That is prohibitivly small as I am trying to write a program which may need up to ~50.

Comment: Why would you need to have so many open files at the same time? Surely you can just read the information you need from the file and close it (and reopen when needed to save changes for example)? 
Windows Mobile devices have limited memory, so you should keep that in mind while designing the application. A user might have other applications running at the same time that you don't know of, and therefore slow down the device or your application.

Comment: Your right, re-designing the application would be the best approach, but once I saw the problem I was also curious as to what the limitations of the device were.

Answer (score 3):

The handle count is limited by available memory. The ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error indicates that the file system driver only see that it cannot create the file you requested, it doesn't know the underlying cause. I cannot say when ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES would be returned, though.

Comment: It does seem to be some arbitary system limit, although its done nothing else so I'm not sure about it being a memory limitation.

As a workaround I've had to implement a simple scheduler for the right to open a file handle... hardly an elegant or complete solution but I have nothing else atm.